# Find Top Root group ID of every group in a hierarchical table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a hierarchical table like this which is is result of query.

```
ID   Parent    Name
1    35         Alex
2    50         John
3    1         Don
4    3         Anietta
5    2         Merin
6    1         Johan
7    4         Tom
8    25         Philp
9    8         Mathew
--------------------------------
```

This is actually filtered rows from a table

So how can I select the top root nodes from the above result using CTE

So final result be something like this

```
ID    Parent    Name
------------------------
1     35        Alex
2     50        John
8     25        Philip
-------------------------
```

From the result it is clear they are the top most root of other members, but their parent is not in the list too. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pseudo code.

```
with data as (
   select 1 ID,  35 Parent,'Alex' as name

union select 2  ID,  50 Parent,          'John' as name
union select 3  ID,  1  Parent,       'Don' as name

union select 4  ID , 3  Parent,       'Anietta' as name
union select 5   ID, 2 Parent,        'Merin' as  name
union select 6   ID, 1 Parent,        'Johan' as name
union select 7   ID ,4  Parent,       'Tom'  as name
union select 8   ID ,25 Parent,       'Philp' as name
union select  9   ID ,8  Parent,       'Mathew' as name
) 
select * from data d1
where not exists (select 1 from data d2 where d2.id = d1.parent)
```